# Finding the last values before a specific value in numpy/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas Series, and I want to find the index/position (or a Boolean mask) of the last times some value appears before some other specific value.

E.g. given:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.randint(10, 1000000)})
```

I want to find all the locations of the 0's that are the last to occur before a 9. So if my array was

```
[9, 0, 3, 0, 1, 9, 4, 9, 0, 0, 9, 4, 0]
```

Only the zeros in position 3 and 9 are of interest to me. Note that in this I am not to worried about what happens to the very last 0 in position 12. I would prefer not to have it in the return set but it is not crucial.

My current method is this:

```
df['last'] = np.nan
df.loc[df.x == 0, 'last'] = 0.0
df.loc[df.x == 9, 'last'] = 1.0
df.last.fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True)
df.loc[df.x == 0, 'last'] = np.nan
df.last.fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True)
df.last.fillna(value=0.0, inplace=True)
df.loc[df.x != 0, 'last'] = 0.0
```

Would anyone have a method that is faster, or more concise?

Comment: What do you want to happen if it's `[0, 3, 9]`?  Are you interested in that 0 or not?  (IOW, how strict are you being with "before"?  Is it "immediately preceding"?)

Comment: In this case I am interested in that 0. "Immediately preceding" is to restrictive (that's why my current solution is convoluted). I have changes the example to make this clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adapting, very simply, @ajcr's answer:

```
s = pd.Series([9, 0, 3, 0, 1, 9, 4, 9, 0, 0, 9, 4, 0]) #using your example array
s = s[s.isin([0,9])]
s[(s == 0) & (s.shift(-1) == 9)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use boolean indexing and `shift`. For example:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([9, 0, 3, 0, 9, 4, 9, 0, 0, 9, 4, 0])
>>> s[(s == 0) & (s.shift(-1) == 9)]
3    0
8    0
dtype: int64
```

This finds the index locations in `s` which have value 0 and are following immediately by 9.

**Edit**: Adapted slightly so that we allow values between a 9 and the last preceding zero (also see @acushner's answer)...

Here's a slightly modified Series `s`; we still want the zeros at indexes 3 and 8:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([9, 0, 3, 0, 9, 4, 9, 0, 0, 4, 9, 0])
>>> t = s[(s == 0) | (s == 9)]
>>> t
0     9
1     0
3     0
4     9
6     9
7     0
8     0
10    9
11    0
```

`t` is a series with all the nines and zeros in `s`. We can retrieve the relevant indices just as before:

```
>>> t[(t == 0) & (t.shift(-1) == 9)]
3    0
8    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: But I want this to work even if there are other numbers between the  0 and the 9. I'll change the example to make this clearer.

Comment: @user1027953 I've edited my answer accordingly (and noticed it's the same as the one given by acushner).

Answer (score 0):

I think this works for general inputs:

```
def find_last_a_before_b(arr, a, b):
    arr = np.asarray(arr)
    idx_a, = np.where(arr == a)
    idx_b, = np.where(arr == b)
    iss = idx_b.searchsorted(idx_a)
    mask = np.concatenate((iss[1:] != iss[:-1],
                           [True if iss[-1] < len(idx_b) else False]))
    return idx_a[mask]

>>> find_last_a_before_b([9, 0, 3, 0, 1, 9, 4, 9, 0, 0, 9, 4, 0], 0, 9)
array([3, 9])
>>> find_last_a_before_b([9, 0, 3, 0, 1, 9, 4, 9, 0, 0, 9, 4, 0], 9, 0)
array([ 0,  7, 10])
```

The key is in the use of `np.searchsorted` to find out which 9 comes after a given 0, then get rid of repeats, and of the last one if it has no 9 after it.